# blockchain.info: "No operations allowed after connection closed."

Tags: blockchain.info

It's not allowing me to see any TX's or addresses. It just says "No operations allowed after connection closed. Connection closed after inability to pick valid new connection during fail-over."

Comment: While the way this is worded looks too localised, it actually might be easily converted to a more general useful question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few minutes ago they restarted the servers, and they won't allow you to make transactions while they're not connected to the network. Since a restart implies a temporary disconnect, you just have to wait a few minutes.